# Jenkins Github Branch Source Plugin Failing with Github Token after today's Github auth changes

Tags: jenkins, github

I am currently facing an issue with Jenkins <> Github integration due to today's Github auth changes deprecating user/pass auth and the current Github branch source plugin.

Deprecation info: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/#removal

Plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin

- Jenkins: 2.249.3
- Github branch source plugin 2.9.1 (latest)
- This jenkins install is private only (not public facing)
- The repo being accessed is private (not public facing)
- The Github token has full repo access

### Issue:

**The plugin forces user/pass auth which Github no longer accepts. The instructions state to put the TOKEN in the password field but it still complains after I've done that:**

> The API can't be accessed using username/password authentication

https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/#removal

Instructions state: "Only username/password credentials are supported" and instructs to add the Token in the password field (screenshot shows this)

The attached screenshot shows the debacle clearly:

[image]

### Questions to ServerFault:

- Am I entering the token wrong for the credentials? I've tried:

  - a null user, with the token as the password
  - The token as the user & pass
  - The token description as the user, with the token as the password
- Normally I would submit a Github issue to a developer about an app issue. However since there is no "Issues" component to submit issues to the plugin developer, I wanted to ask my question here, in case others have hit this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly same story here. Your post inspired me to dig deeper and I found a solution.

Go to the "System Configuration" (sorry, my Browser is set to german and I don't know the exact wording) and create new credentials for the GitHub server in "Secret Text" format. Use the Personal Access Token as secret and give it a description.

Verify with the "Test connection" button. It should print out the following:

`Credentials verified for user your-cool-username, rate limit: 4876`

[GitHub API server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myUVn.png)

Now in the project it still forces me to use username/password credentials but it somehow seems to work with the global GitHub API settings we changed.

[My username/password credential settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPe7w.png)

There references in the plugins code about checkout via SSH (see [here in the repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin/search?q=SSHCheckoutTrait)), but I couldn't find a way to use key auth. It puzzles me a bit that my solution works, I didn't expect that.

Edit: I actually found a checkout via [SSH checkout option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkD66.png), not sure/expecting do better.

Comment: Confirmed. After re-configuring the global settings for Github **AND** the project settings, this is finally working. Thank you.

Comment: @user5626219 had good/correct info too in their answer, but this answer is the solution that actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> - a null user, with the token as the password
> - The token as the user & pass
> - The token description as the user, with the token as the password

None of these worked for me, however

- the GitHub username as user, the token as password

did.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Creating a new token with the link in the [Github Branch Source Plugin docs](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-admin-guide/github-branch-source-plugin#_selecting_github_organization_credentials) and adding a new credential with username and token solved the issue for us.

I think the solution by @andreas-bretschneider does not use this plugin, just individual jobs and global github integration (which didn't fix the issue for us).